# SwiftUI: How to use Github package?

Tags: github, swiftui, package

I am trying to use this package from Github https://github.com/yashthaker7/NumberPicker

I successfully manage to add `pod 'NumberPicker'` to my podfile, but when I try to implement the code I get a bunch of errors.

How I implement the code is by adding this to the action part of a simple button:

```
func openNumberPicker() {
    let numberPicker = NumberPicker(delegate: self, maxNumber: 300) // set max number 
    numberPicker.bgGradients = [.red, .yellow]
    numberPicker.tintColor = .white
    numberPicker.heading = "Weight"
    numberPicker.defaultSelectedNumber = 150 // set default selected number

    self.present(numberPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am using `SwiftUI` and not `Storyboard` with which the package is originally written in.

**Any ideas on what to do?**

Comment: The code you have provided doesn't use SwiftUI at all. You likely need a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`

Comment: Im not sure how to do that. How would I go about it? @loremipsum

Comment: Look up SwiftUI and `UIAlertController` or `UIImagePickerController` likely a similar setup if `NumberPicker` is a `UIViewController`